# Send Glympse API Web API?

Tags: glympse

Besides showing a web mapview of Glympse.

Is there any JS lib to do the sending of Glympse via Web API? It would be useful to develop mobile / desktop web application that uses the geolocation HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment map control is the only public API that we provide for the Web. We are going to extend the set of exposed APIs and supported platforms over time. Keep an eye on our announcements!